# Angular web component shows nothing

Tags: javascript, angular, web-component

I have the following problem. I need to something reusable across different UI frameworks or just plain html/css/js. I found that I can create a web component within Angular framework so I did test app. Everything seems alright but when I open the index.html which includes the script which loads the `.js` file and tag with my app there is nothing of it in browser. Does anybody know where I have something wrong?

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

My AppComponent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp',
  template: `
    <p>custom-web-comp works!</p>
    <p>Data:</p>
    <p *ngFor="let data of webService.getData()">
      {{data.name}} | {{data.value}}
    </p>
`
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(public webService: WebCompService) { }
}
```

My AppModule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [],
  entryComponents: [
    AppComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule implements DoBootstrap {

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

  ngDoBootstrap() {
    const el = createCustomElement(AppComponent, {
      injector: this.injector
    });
    customElements.define('my-comp', el);
  }
}
```

In package.json I have this script:

```
"build:elements": "ng build --output-hashing none && node build-elements.js"
```

build-elements.js:

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const concat = require('concat');

(async function build() {
  const files = [
    './dist/ng-element-demo/runtime-es5.js',
    './dist/ng-element-demo/runtime-es2015.js',
    './dist/ng-element-demo/polyfills-es5.js',
    './dist/ng-element-demo/polyfills-es2015.js',
    './dist/ng-element-demo/scripts.js',
    './dist/ng-element-demo/main-es5.js',
    './dist/ng-element-demo/main-es2015.js'
  ];

  await fs.ensureDir('elements');
  await concat(files, 'elements/ng-element-demo.js');
})();
```

Then I am trying this in index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Testing the News Web Component</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <my-comp></my-comp>
      
    <script src="./ng-element-demo.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But browser render just "Hello" even when the ng-element.demo.js is successfully loaded (can be seen in dev tools).

Thank you for any help

Answer (score -1):

I think what you need to do is to place the file inside assets folder. You can create a js folder there and add the ng-element-demo.js inside it. Then in your angular.json file, you need to add it there under scripts.

```
So you will have something like this
 "scripts": [
              "src/assets/js/ng-element-demo.js"
            ]
```

Comment: I didn´t try your solution yet because I need use this web component also in non-angular  app. I need some universal solution also for plain html/css/js project and there is no angular.json file.